# How to pass variables in recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I want to do something like recursive dfs and my main function only gets one parameter - the state I need to get to. My helper function can get any set of parameters. What I need is to get to the end state and remember my moves. So I think I can call the functions recursively and reduce the state (represented by length I need to reach) each time but how do I save the way to get there? I wanted to use a string but I can't pass it along...

The idea of the code is to get to a certain length when I can go in steps of 1 or 2

Pseudo code:

```
helper(path, step_length, length_to_go):
    if(step_length == length)
        return path.concat(step_length);
    Main(length_to_go - step_length);

Main(length):
    string path = "";
    int step1 = 1, step2 = 2;
    helper(path, step1, length);
    helper(path, step2, length);
```

The problem is in the call to main, the path string wouldn't carry on, wouldn't it?

Comment: It might be clearer to express yourself in non-pseudo code.

Comment: Or at least more detailed pseudo code, this is just too abstracted to understand what you are trying to do. Also, you should reformat to fix your code block formatting

Comment: @Marcin - I edited my post, hope its clearer.

Answer (score 3):

The main method can create an empty collection and pass it to the helper.

Each call in the helper can update the collection with its step.

You will not have to add a parameter to Main, but you will have to add one to Helper.

Comment: Assume I do do that. Then the collection is empty at the first call, and by the second call it is reinitialized, isn't it?

Comment: Create and initialize the collection in Main. Add to it in Helper.